# Fetch global $post inside theme functions.php of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress.

In the `themes/my_theme/functions.php` I want to do something like the below:

```
global $post;
$is_mobile = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mobile')[0];
```

Then I found the `global $post` is null.

I tried:

```
function mobile_actions() {
    global $post;
    var_dump($post);
}
add_action('wp_head', 'mobile_actions');
```

It's ok.

And:

```
function mobile_actions() {
    global $post;
    var_dump($post);
}
add_action('wp_loaded', 'mobile_actions');
```

With no luck.

So, if I want to fetch that `global $post`, which hook is the earliest I should use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *earliest* you could do this would be in the ['wp' hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp). This hook runs the [register_globals()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src//wp-includes/class-wp.php#L484) function which exposes `$post`.

However, `'wp_head'` would also be adequate.

Comment: Wow! It worked perfectly! I'm trying to make a redirection, so `wp` hook is fit for me!